Seeking Guidance on Final Year BS Physics Project Topics with Limited Experimental Facilities
I am currently in the final year of my BS Physics program, and I am in the process of selecting a topic for my final year project. However, my university lacks experimental and laboratory facilities, which means I am limited to theoretical work and online resources. This has made it challenging to narrow down a project idea that is feasible under these constraints.
Given my situation, I am looking for guidance on:
Project Ideas:
Which topics would be suitable for a theoretical or computational physics project?
Are there specific subfields (e.g., quantum mechanics, electrodynamics, or computational physics) that lend themselves well to theoretical or simulation-based work?
Resources and Tools:
What tools or software (e.g., Python, Qiskit, Mathematica) would be beneficial to learn for such projects?
Are there any open datasets, simulations, or platforms that I can use for my project?
Making the Most of Online Resources:
How can I effectively leverage online resources (e.g., arXiv, educational YouTube channels, MOOCs) to supplement my work?
I am passionate about topics such as quantum mechanics and electromagnetism, but I am open to suggestions that align with the constraints I have. I would greatly appreciate any advice on project ideas, resources, or tips from those who have faced similar challenges.

This question is off topic$^1$ for this site.
[1] (psst: Cavendish Exp can be done with stuff from the trash. On theory: I did classical "Maxwells" eqs for $SU(3)$....but Jefimenko's Eq would be cooler).
